# Visual studio code closing alone while executing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently Visual Studio Code has been closing while executing a program that takes around 2:30h to complete. I am really confused, one thing I noticed is that there is a number [3] in the tag of the file I am executing that was not there before as it can be seen in the next image:
[image]

I am executing the program with admin rights but never that created any problem. Any solution of idea why this happens?

Comment: This number means there are 3 problems in your file. Next to the terminal, there is a problems section, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @dasJulian There error is "line too long (87>79 characters)".

Comment: Any other errors?